# How do you stop setInterval from creating multiple instances on .load()'s?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When a user clicks a nav button on my site they call a `.load()`, i.e.,  `$("#main_window").load("file.php");` If file.php contains JavaScript along with a `setInterval` timer then if a user clicks the nav button multiple times they'll create multiple `setInterval`s. How do I stop this and only have one timer at all times?

Obtaining the ID of the timer doesn't help because `.load` resets global variables. Thus I'm unable to prevent multiple timers on repeated `.load()`.

```
var myVar;

console.log(myVar);  // will be undefined when .load() calls this file again.

myVar = setInterval(reload, 5000);

console.log(myVar); // A new ID will be created on each .load(), but all old instances will continue to fire

function reload() {
  $(tableName).DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
  console.log("reloaded"); 
}
```

Console.log output: with two `.loads()`:

> undefined
>
> 27
>
> undefined
>
> 34

Comment: I don't want to stop all timeouts as I have others on my site that are used for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myVar){
  clearInterval(myVar)
}
var myVar;

console.log(myVar);  // will be undefined when .load() calls this file again.

myVar = setInterval(reload, 5000);

console.log(myVar); // A new ID will be created on each .load(), but all old instances will continue to fire

function reload() {
  $(tableName).DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
  console.log("reloaded"); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.